# How can the SameSite attribute be added to the Omnipay PHPSESSID cookie?

Tags: cookies, omnipay

Omnipay sets the PHPSESSID cookie which now requires the SameSite attribute. How can SameSite be added to the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the code, I'm not convinced Omnipay has a [specific cookie dependency](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay/search?q=cookie&unscoped_q=cookie). The `PHPSESSID` cookie is controlled through your `php.ini` configuration. You can set this with the [`session.cookie_samesite`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-samesite) key in the file or using [`session_set_cookie_params()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).

You will need to determine what the correct `SameSite` attribute to set for your site is. I would try setting `Lax` first and then test your checkout flow, especially any stages that feature a redirect (such as returning from 3-D Secure verification or PayPal). I would not recommend setting your main session cookie to `SameSite=None; Secure` **unless** your entire site is used in an embedded, third-party context. However, if things are broken you can use this as a temporary fix, just keep in mind you are losing the security benefits.

Ideally, you should also ensure that the cookie is set to `Secure` and `HttpOnly` if possible.